# Why does “du -sh” show different folder size after copy?

Tags: du

I want to have a simple backup and copied all files from one folder to another. OS is Debian.

- When I do a `du -sh`on the source folder I get 436G.
- When doing the same on the destination I only get 384G.

If I mount both folders via Samba to a Windows machine both folders have the same size.

Can somebody explain me, why `du` shows different sizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`du`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du) has an option for `--apparent-size` which might help you. I would guess that the two disks have different block sizes.  If a file only partially uses a block nothing else can use the rest, so by default du counts disk usage in blocks.

To get the block size that an ext filesystem on /dev/sda1 uses you can do:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'Block size'
```

If you are concerned that not all of your files were copied you can get a program like [`cfv`](http://cfv.sourceforge.net) to create a recursive hash for the original files and verify the backup with it.

**Generate Checksums From Originals**:

```
cfv -p /path/to/origin -C -rr -f /tmp/checksum.sha1
```

**Verify Backup Against Checksums**:

```
cfv -p /path/to/backup -T -u -f /tmp/checksum.sha1
```